# I cannot access my yahoo email via Thunderbird anymore. What is the best way to regain access to yahoo mail account?

Tags: email, yahoo

What are the settings people are using to get access to yahoo mail account reliably these days?

Comment: This is a site for programming questions, yours doesn't appear to be one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the official uk.yahoo.com website

Click mail in top right corner

Log in

Complete! :)